# How do you inject services from required modules into module config function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a separate services module and I need a service injected into the config function of a dependent module.

```
angular.module('app', ['app.services'], function(myservice) {/*use myservice*/})
  .controller('mycontroller', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.message = myservice.sayHello();
  });

angular.module('app.services', [], function($provide) {
  $provide.service('myservice', function() {
    return {sayHello: function() { return 'hello'; }};
  });
});
```

I've also create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FzGmL/

The code will blow up with *Unknown provider: myservice from app*

If you remove the `myservice` argument from the `app` module config function, the `mycontroller` constructor function is able to have `myservice` injected just fine.

How can `myservice` be injected into the config function of the `app` module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `Module.run()` method, It does initialization work for you after the injector is done loading.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['app.services'])
   .run(function(myservice) {
      //stuff here.
   });
```

Comment: Look at that. It's right in the docs. Thanks! http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#run